# Please help: If $a \not\subset B$ and $a \in A$, is $a$ an element of $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning set theory and this is a homework question. I answered, "not necessarily because nothing is telling us whether $a$ is an element of $B$ and an element cannot be a subset". Am I right? What is the correct answer?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer is correct, the reasoning isn't (or worded weirdly). I would say that since $A$ isn't a subset, there is an element of $A$ that isn't in $B$, so hence, $a$ could be that element.

Comment: I think it would be good to give a specific counterexample

Comment: Try $B=\emptyset$

Comment: @freethinker36 Given that we seem to have misinterpreted your question, it seems that the set $A$ has nothing to do with the question. Does this seem right to you?

Comment: I think it is a trick question.

Comment: @DonThousand a isn't a subset, not A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. We know that there are elements of $A$ which are not in $B$, and there may be elements of $A$ that *are* in $B$. If we pick an element of $A$, it could fall into either of these two categories.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you should come up with a counterexample rather than using ambiguous descriptions.

Counterexample: Let $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{0\}$ and $a=1$, then clearly $A$ is not a subset of $B$. However, $a\in A$ but $a\notin B$.

Thanks to @Sambo, if we take $a=0$, then $a$ is both in $A$ and $B$. Therefore we conclude: If $A\not\subset B$, then “$a\in A$” has nothing to do with “$a\in B$”.

Comment: In your example, $a$ *is* an element of $B$

Comment: I would add a second case, $a=0$, to show that the statement "$x\in B$" could be either true or false.

Comment: or I should say *was*, since you now edited

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sorry sorry. I’ve seen it and fixed it.

Comment: but it is a ⊄ B not A ⊄B.

Comment: My suspicions, I am not certain, is that it is a trick question because a cannot be a subset. Elements can only belong to a set not be a subset, not sure if Im correct.

Comment: @freethinker36 The operators $\subset$ and $\not\subset$ are only defined for sets. So if $a$ is not a set, it makes no sense to say “$a\not\subset B$”.

Comment: @freethinker36 Also, if your problem is like this, then $A$ has nothing to do with $B$. That would make this problem meaningless.

Comment: Exactly! That's why I think it is a trick question.